# Can we run android operating system inside a kubernetes pod?

Tags: android, kubernetes, mobile, operating-system

I have been trying to run the android open source operating system  inside a  pod which is containerized with in the Kubernetes and trying to access it. The problem I want to solve is that the android should be running inside a pod and we should be able to run multiple pods where every android system is individual and we can be able to access them remotely.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about sounds like a stateful workload for which you should use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) rather than a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). As you can read in the docs, it guarantees uniqueness of each pod:

> StatefulSet is the workload API object used to manage stateful
> applications.
>
> Manages the deployment and scaling of a set of
> [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/),  *and
> provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness*  of these Pods.
>
> Like a
> [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/),
> a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container
> spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity
> for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but
> are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it
> maintains across any rescheduling.
>
> If you want to use storage volumes to provide persistence for your
> workload, you can use a StatefulSet as part of the solution. Although
> individual Pods in a StatefulSet are susceptible to failure, the
> persistent Pod identifiers make it easier to match existing volumes to
> the new Pods that replace any that have failed.

If you're running it on some cloud environment, you can expose it via [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) service type so you can access it remotely.